# Stratified sampling for regression

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction, sampling, bigdata

I need to do regression analysis using SVM kernels on the large sets of data. My laptop is not able to handle and it takes hours to finish running. Is there any good way to reduce the dataset size without affecting the (much) quality of the model? Will stratified sampling work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **dozens** of ways of reducing SVM complexity, probably the easiest ones involve **approximating Kernel space projection**. In particular libraries such as [scikit-learn provides functions to do this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html) kind of explicit projection, which followed by a linear SVM - can be trained realatively fast.